# psycopg2.errors.NumericValueOutOfRange: ОШИБКА: целое вне диапазона

Tags: python, psycopg2

У меня есть база данных, я пытаюсь туда записать большое число, к примеру 705049903050784769, используя тип данных BIGINT, но выдает ошибку, при попытке внести данные(пытаюсь внести в ячейку id):

```
psycopg2.errors.NumericValueOutOfRange: ОШИБКА:  целое вне диапазона
```

Код:

```
cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
    id BIGINT,
    name TEXT,
    cash BIGINT,
    mes BIGINT,
    mesnum BIGINT,
    mute BIGINT,
    marry BIGINT,
    marryname TEXT,
    voicetime BIGINT,
    voiceprivat BIGINT,
    voiceevent BIGINT,
    textevent BIGINT,
    voicetech BIGINT,
    texttech BIGINT,
    mutenum BIGINT,
    unmutenum BIGINT
    )""")
cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO users (id,name,cash,mes,mesnum,mute,marry,marryname,voicetime,voiceprivat,voiceevent,textevent,voicetech,texttech,mutenum,unmutenum) VALUES ({member.id},'{member}',{5},{0},{0},{0},{0},' ',{0},{0},{0},{0},{0},{0},{0},{0})")
connection.commit()
```

Что это может быть?

Comment: Предоставьте скрипт для воспроизведения ошибки с конкретным числом.

Comment: Может у вас ранее была уже создана эта таблица с другими параметрами столбцов и этот скрипт по созданию таблицы просто не отрабатывает? )

Comment: @CrazyElf да, создал ранее таблицу с инт значениями, тоже думал об этом, просто не видел таблицы вот и решил, что не создалась, спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

```
"""Для начала создайте базу данных и таблицу.
   Потом поочерёдно убирайте комментарии и запускайте скрипт.

"""
"""doc"""
import psycopg2


def main():
    """doc"""

    try:
        users_db = psycopg2.connect(dbname='users_db', user='administrator', host='127.0.0.1',
                                    password='12345678', port=5432)
        users_db.autocommit = True
        cursor = users_db.cursor()

        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM users")
        print(cursor.fetchall())

    except psycopg2.OperationalError as exception:
        print(f'I am unable to connect to the database.')

    try:
        print()
        #cursor.execute("INSERT INTO users(main_id, user_id) VALUES(1, 705049903050784769)") # 705049903050784769 ваше число для примера
        # cursor.execute("INSERT INTO users(main_id, user_id) VALUES(2, 9223372036854775807)") # MAXIMUM BIGINT 9,223,372,036,854,775,807
        # cursor.execute("INSERT INTO users(main_id, user_id) VALUES(4, 9223372036854775808)")  # MAXIMUM BIGINT 9,223,372,036,854,775,807 + 1
    except psycopg2.errors.NumericValueOutOfRange as error:
        print(error)

    # cursor.execute("DELETE FROM users")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Я добавил значения bigint.

Ваше число и максимальное значение для **BIGINT** в **PostgreSQL**.
[image: Результат]

И последний вызов максимальное значение + 1, то есть 9223372036854775808.

[image: Результат]

Comment: У вас ОШИБКА:  целое вне диапазона, предположу что не bigint.